# Facing trouble in loading packages in R studio

Tags: r

I installed R studio version 4.0.2. Since then I am unable to load various packages like Hmisc. Error that I get is ***"Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’:package ‘jpeg’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it"***. I tried installing the package and also added dependencies=True argument but still getting the same error. as soon as I try to add Hmisc again same error pops with a different package name that requires installation.

[image]

Comment: Please install `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Thats quite inconvenient, but normal just reinstall all your packages as you need them. In case of your error message as Bappa Das says you need to reinstall gridExtra.

Comment: If you google a little bit, there are also ways to have a smoother way of taking your packages to a new a version. But in general with a new R version packages have to be rebuild. (but you could e.g. do this for all packages at once)

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` look like? Are all paths under your control? Are you trying to use packages from an R 3.* version?

Comment: I installed gridExtra package but after that as soon as I tried library(Hmisc);I can see the error again as "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’:package ‘checkmate’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it"

Comment: @MrFlick library path is "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"

Comment: So that's the base path that `find.package("checkmate")`  would return? It seems odd there is only one path there. Are you running R as an administrator or something? You did reinstall packages with `install.packages()` when you installed R 4.0, right? You didn't copy over any files manually from previous installations? Do you possibly have an `.RData` file in your working directory from an old version of R that's being loaded at start up?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes on running find.pacakage command for any package I get the same path.No am not running the path as admin.